# Keep previous element of collection in Java for loop even on continue

Tags: java, loops, syntax

I need to match next element with previous. On condition I would like to `continue` iteration. But I don't like copy/paste assignment to previous element:

```
List<Type> all;
Type prev = null;
for (Type curr : all) {
    if (prev == null) {
        prev = curr;
        continue;
    }
    if (isBad(curr)) {
        prev = curr;
        continue;
    }
    if (! curr.match(prev)) {
        prev = curr;
        continue;
    }
    process(prev, curr);
    prev = curr;
}
```

How can I avoid `prev = curr` duplication?

I think that solution:

```
for (Type curr : all) {
    if (prev != null && !isBad(curr) && curr.match(prev)) {
        process(prev, curr);
    }
    prev = curr;
}
```

is cheating because `process(prev, curr);` shouldn't have indenting. Error checking logic shouldn't bother with main execution logic (forcing of indentation).

Comment: Are the three separate `if` conditions just for demonstration purposes or are there really no instructions between them?

Comment: I received answers before proper edited question. Please delete it.

Comment: What's the matter with the indentation? This looks like academic style code cleaning. Anyway, the question is whether you want to `process` *bad* `prev` items? If yes, then your "cheating" code is just fine.

Comment: Error checking and pre-conditions shouldn't influence main execution flow. By indenting main code due to checks you mix checks and operation flow. Do you indent your code due to `Assert`? I think don't...

Comment: Error checking and pre-conditions **is** part of the main execution flow. `Assert.assert...` is part of testing. `assert` will terminate invalid data, that!s another matter. In your case, you are willing to process `bad` values as long as they are in the `prev` reference. I suggest to work on the context of this method.

Comment: I chose bad name for `isBad`  )). My business logic operates on flight statuses and I look for pair - canceled flight and new flight, which come sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop with indexes, so you can read 'ahead' and you shouldn't use a variable for the previous one, the last value of i have to be size-1 in this case.

```
    List<Type> all;
    Type prev = null;
    for(int i=0; i<all.size()-1; i++) {
        if(isBad(all.get(i)) {
            continue;
        }
        if(all.get(i).match(all.get(i+1)) {
            continue;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: This 'read-ahead' thingy is not supported by java Iterators. You can use [Google's guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21) what has [PeekingIterator](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the continue statements and make the code clearer by combining the 3 if statements :

```
for (Type curr : all) {
    if (prev != null && !isBad(curr) && curr.match(prev)) {
        process(prev, curr);
    }
    prev = curr;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I update answer. It have point in which your solution is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use OR (||).

i.e.

```
if (prev == null || isBad(curr) || ! curr.match(prev) ) {
    prev = curr;
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all "continue" from your script.

Either do this by linking the if statements together using "else if" and having process() in an else block at the end, or do so by combining the conditions and swapping the blocks:

```
for (Type curr : all) {
    if (prev != null &&
        !isBad(curr) &&
        curr.match(prev)) {
        process(prev, curr);
    }
    prev = curr;
}
```

or

```
for (Type curr : all) {
    if (prev != null) {
    }
    else if (isBad(curr)) {
    }
    else if (! curr.match(prev)) {
    }
    else {
        process(prev, curr);
    }
    prev = curr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use OR (||) and put the condition in a method with relevant name:

```
public void myMethod(){
    List<Type> all;
    Type prev = null;
    for (Type curr : all) {
            if (isContinue()) {
                prev = curr;
                continue;
            }
            process(prev, curr);
            prev = curr;
    }
}


private boolean isContinue(){
    return (prev == null || isBad(curr) || !curr.match(prev);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think about:

```
List<Type> all;
Type prev = null;
Type curr = null;
Iterator<Type> iter = all.iterator();
for (; iter.haSNext(); prev = curr) {
    curr = iter.next();
    if (prev == null)
        continue;
    if (isBad(curr))
        continue;
    if (! curr.match(prev))
        continue;

    process(prev, curr);
}
```

I wrote [blog post about this topic with more detailed examples](http://blog.defun.work/post-631f6b21-01b6-4d50-8e0f-13f59bd66fc2.html).

As a result I find out that Java miss `goto` statement with which implementation with imposed restrictions would be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you do the same in all the if-s. So you can use the or `||` within the `if` :

```
for (Type curr : all) {
    if (prev == null || isBad(curr) || ! curr.match(prev)) {
        prev = curr;
        continue;
    }
    process(prev, curr);
    prev = curr;
}
```